# Android - inject keyboard events

Tags: android, keyboard, inject

I have a custom Android in which I need to inject keyboard events. Or maybe better said, I want to "type" a string that is generated in a service into wherever the Cursor currently is.

Permissions are not the problem, I can be root and I can sign my app with the system key.

There is Instrumentation with sendStringSync. But this only works for ASCII characters. What about german, french and other chars? Same thing for "input text". I did not find a robust solution.

In other words, what do I have to do in order to make Android type a string as if it came from the virtual keyboard?
Please note that maybe the keyboard is visible, even then my string shall be entered.

Comment: Not tried this, but you could look at the input command, you call it with `Runtime.getRuntime().exec("input text \"hello world\"");`

Comment: Or implement a keyboard. https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/text/creating-input-method.html

Comment: Yes but as I said input text too, only works for standard characters. Once there is something like an umlaut, it crashes. Implementing a keyboard could help but I'd have to put a lot of effort into it, I'd create something new that must be chosen as standard or else it won't work. So I'd like to inject my text at another place that is independent of the current keyboard.

Comment: Oh yeah. Oh well, good luck.